# Create new variable from DataFrame with names and set them as False boolean values

Tags: python, pandas

I have an pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
output:
        0                    1               3         ...
0     Subject            Importance         Hour       ...
1   Linear Algebra       Mandatory        Afternoon    ...
2   Data Science         Optional          Morning     ...
3   Data Structure       Mandatory          Night      ...
4      ...                   ...             ...
```

What I know so far is that, I can get the value of the `Subject` with:

```
df[0].tolist()
```

That will generate an list like:

```
['Linear Algebra', 'Data Science', 'Data Structure', ...]
```

But I need to create an dictionary that has the name of the subject, and the value defined as `False`

```
subject_dict = { 
    'Linear Algebra': False, 
    'Data Science' : False,
    'Data Structure': False
}
```

So that I can access them in order to modify from false to true. My first though was to use a dictionary, but thinking right know I may use also with a list.

How can I solve this?

I've tried:

```
subject_dict = df[0].to_dict()
```

but it didn't work.

Perhaps in a list but how it's going to be the iteration?

Comment: You may want dict comprehension `{key: False for key in df[0].tolist()}` ?

Comment: You can use dictionary comprehension on the output of the to_list method.

Comment: Almost as if that method was designed for this. @enke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict-comprehension:

```
dct = {s: False for s in df[0][1:]]
```

Or use `dict.fromkeys`:

```
dct = dict.fromkeys(df[0][1:], False)
```

Output:

```
>>> dct
{'Linear Algebra': False,
 'Data Science': False,
 'Data Structure': False}
```